# MVC Ads tracking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, google-analytics

**C#**

```
   public ActionResult GetBanners()
        {
        List<BannerImage> bannerImages = new List<BannerImage>();
        bannerImages.add(new BannerImage(){Id = 1, TargetUrl = "http://www.google.com", ImageUrl= 'Image1'});
        bannerImages.add(new BannerImage(){Id = 2, TargetUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com", ImageUrl= 'Image2'});
        bannerImages.add(new BannerImage(){Id = 3, TargetUrl = "http://www.msn.com", ImageUrl= 'Image3'});
return view(bannerImages);
        }
```

**View (.cshtml)**

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Areas.Admin.ViewModel.BannerImage>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" >    

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a onclick="ClickMethod()" href = "@item.TargetUrl"> <img src = "@item.ImageUrl" /> </a>
        </td>       
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I am displaying the external website's banner ads in my application. Here I am facing challenge as to how to track:
1. Views
2. Impressions (Means ad is visible to the user within the screen bounds)
3. Impressions today
4. Clicks Today

**My Approach**

```
 public ActionResult GetBanners()
    {

      // before showing the ads, I am inserting the ads for view in Userads database table
        Updatebannerviews();

    }

   public ActionResult ClickMethod()
    {

      // I am inserting the ads for clicks in Userads database table
        UpdateBannerClicks();
        return json("Success", JsonBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

 public ActionResult Impressions()
    {

      // I am inserting the ads for impressions, in Userads database table
        UpdateBannerImpressions();
        return json("Success", JsonBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Is it a right way? Or is there a better way? Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Overall, it is same with my way in previous project. It is right way

Comment: @HienNguyen, Thanks!